# Realm Adapter 2.0 - Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder

Tags: android, realm

I'm using Realm Adapter in my project for real-time sync.

It works sometimes but sometimes it crashes giving the above error, cannot figure out why

It crashes when I save an object to Realm, in-turn which is consumed by the adapter

This is how I'm saving

```
 public void saveDestinations(Destination destination) {
    mRealm.executeTransaction(realm -> mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(destination));
}
```

Here's how I'm getting the data into my adapter

```
  private void initUI() {
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    destinationRealmResults = RealmManager.destinationDAO().loadDestination();
    adapter = new RecentAdapter(destinationRealmResults, getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    validateRecyclerView();
}
```

This is my adapter

```
public class RecentAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Destination, RecentAdapter.ViewHolder> {


private Context context;
private Preferences preferences;

public RecentAdapter(OrderedRealmCollection<Destination> orderedRealmCollection, Context context) {
    super(orderedRealmCollection, true);
    this.context = context;
    preferences = new Preferences(context);
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recent, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.address.setText(getData().get(position).getAddress());
    holder.date.setText(getData().get(position).getDate());
    if (getData().get(position).isFavorite())
        holder.favCheck.setChecked(true);
    else
        holder.favCheck.setChecked(false);

}

private void animateCheck(CheckBox checkBox) {
    checkBox.setScaleX(0);
    checkBox.setScaleY(0);
    checkBox.animate().scaleX(1).scaleY(1).start();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.address)
    TextView address;
    @BindView(R.id.check_fav)
    CheckBox favCheck;
    @BindView(R.id.date)
    TextView date;

    @OnClick(R.id.card_view)
    public void createDestination() {
        if (!preferences.getBoolean(SharedPrefsKeys.HAS_TRACKING_STARTED)) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("Start Trip")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want set this destination?")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            EventBus.getDefault().post(new AppEvents.SelectStartTripEvent(getData().get(getAdapterPosition())));
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_room_red_500_24dp)
                    .show();
        } else {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new AppEvents.StartTripError(true));
        }

    }

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        favCheck.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v;
            if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                RealmManager.destinationDAO().saveToFavorites(getData().get(getAdapterPosition()));
                animateCheck(checkBox);
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new AppEvents.UpdateFavDestinationEvent(true));
            } else {
                RealmManager.destinationDAO().removeFromFavorites(getData().get(getAdapterPosition()));
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new AppEvents.UpdateFavDestinationEvent(true));
            }

        });
    }
}
```

}

Event Bus (Events)

```
 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
}

@Subscribe
public void validateRecyclerView(AppEvents.UpdateFavDestinationEvent event) {
    if (event.isMustUpdate()) {
        validateRecyclerView();
    }
}


  public void validateRecyclerView() {
    if (adapter.getData() != null && adapter.getData().size() == 0) {
        loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where and how do you handle the `EventBus` events?

Comment: Events are handled in the another Fragment

Comment: What version of Realm are you using?

Comment: Realm Version - 3.0

Comment: Updating to Realm 3.1.1 should fix your problem

Comment: Ok, I'll try this out